# Can I disable the SonarQube summary comments on our GitLab Merge Requests

Tags: gitlab, sonarqube

As the title suggests, I'm curious if there is a way to disable those annoying SonarQube analysis summary comments on our GitLab Merge Requests, without disabling the SonarQube analysis altogether.

I found this Sonar issue: [SCCOMM-19 (closed)](https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/SCCOMM-19)
which seemed to indicate that the feature is available for GitHub projects. But I can't find the setting they reference in our project settings. (See screenshot at bottom for how the SonarQube settings are organized for our GitLab project).

I tried adding both of the following lines to our sonar-project.properties file. Though the comments persisted.

```
sonar.pullrequest.github.summary_comment=false
sonar.pullrequest.gitlab.summary_comment=false
```

I also found this Sonar community [thread](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/disable-gitlab-merge-request-comments/84988/3), which is specific to GitLab. Based on the Community managers response, it seems like the feature may not available.

But I don't want to give up hope that easily. I am curious if anyone has been able to disable the summary comments without disabling the sonar analysis job altogether. Thanks in advance!

[image: SonarQube settings for GitLab project]